# python: send value of a variable instead of its name to function

Tags: python, django, function, class, attributes

I have a class like this:

```
class Rank (models.Model):
      respect=models.IntegerField(max_length=3)
      #some other attributes
```

`Rank` has many attributes (the first of which is `respect`).

The names of the attributes of `Rank` are stored in the `list`, `attributes`.

I would like to iterate through them, setting them to `somevalue`, an arbitrary variable.

I'm attempting:

```
rank=Rank()
for att in attributes:
     rank.att=somevalue #I want rank.(value of att) instead of this
```

Comment: What function are you trying to send the value of a variable to instead of the variable name?

Comment: class constructor function
if you look at the code you will find out

Comment: Your question is kinda misleading. Python uses pass by reference and the only way to pass by value is to use a deep copy of the object (which is terribly inefficient). Also I don't even see any functions in your code besides __init__.

Comment: @ShashankGupta No, python does *not* use pass by reference. If it did, this question would make some sense.

Comment: He wants `rank.att` to actually mean `rank.{value_of_att}` I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're trying to do is set a value to an attribute by name. This is what the setattr built in method is for.

```
rank=Rank()
for att in attributes:
     setattr(rank, att, somevalue)
```

Comment: But site doesn't allow me to set your answer as correct answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `*args` or `**kwargs` wildcard argument.  Try the following to see how it works:

```
def foo(*args, **kwargs):
    print args
    print kwargs

foo(1,2,3)
foo(a=1,b=2,c=3)
foo(1,2,z=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can inject attributes to objects using `setattr`

```
for att in attributes:
    setattr(classobj, att.name, att.value)
```

Note however that this may work or not because the class could have been based on a metaclass that inspects the attributes when creating the class object.

Adding attributes or methods later may work or not, depending on what kind of magic has been used in the metaclass.

If the class wants to inspect the attributes at creation time the only solution (without messing with the class specific magic) is using `eval` of a string.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can't pass a name of a variable to a function - python is call by value only*

What you can do, and I think this is what you want, is use `getattr` and `setattr`:

```
for att in attributes:
     print getattr(rank, att)
     setattr(rank, att, somevalue)
```

`*` I'm aware of the sect who believe that Python has some other calling convention. It's not a thing.